# Web.api - extend/manipulate json before send to angular?

Tags: c#, json

I'am learning c# and angular2. I build a web.api and want to to extend/manipulate the json (in order to reduce the api-calls).

In my web.api I just get the first product:

```html
            return _context.ProductData
                .Where(c => productgrouplist.Contains(c.groupid) && c.date > DateTime.Now)
                .Include(c => c.group)
                .GroupBy(p => p.groupid)
                .Select(g => g.OrderBy(p => p.date).First());
```

At the moment the main json is like this:

```html
[
  {
    "productid": 183438053218929,
    "date": "2016-12-06T21:45:00",
    "groupid": 1,
    "title": "Testproduct1",
    "description": "Test1",
    "category": null,
    "level_sub": "",
    "level_top": "test1",
    "group": {
      "groupid": 1,
      "groupname": "Cat1",
      "grouplong": "Testcat1 long",
      "grouplastupdate": "2016-11-30T00:00:00"
    }
  },
  {
    "productid": 183438053218940,
    "date": "2016-12-06T20:45:00",
    "groupid": 2,
    "title": "Testproduct2",
    "description": "Test2",
    "category": null,
    "level_sub": "",
    "level_top": "test2",
    "group": {
      "groupid": 2,
      "groupname": "Cat2",
      "grouplong": "Testcat2 long",
      "grouplastupdate": "2016-11-30T00:00:00"
    }
  }

]
```

and get the following by a new web.api call (1 per group). Thats why I want the next product of the same group should be as a follower within the first one. Is this possible within a (core) web.api? Groupinfo does not need to be there in follower. Perfect would be a json-result like this:

```html
[
  {
    "productid": 183438053218929,
    "date": "2016-12-06T21:45:00",
    "groupid": 1,
    "title": "Testproduct1",
    "description": "Test1",
    "category": null,
    "level_sub": "",
    "level_top": "test1",
    "group": {
      "groupid": 1,
      "groupname": "Cat1",
      "grouplong": "Testcat1 long",
      "grouplastupdate": "2016-11-30T00:00:00"
    }
 "follower":   {
  "productid": 183438053218930,
  "date": "2016-12-06T22:45:00",
  "groupid": 1,
  "title": "Testproduct1bfollow",
  "description": "Test1b",
  "category": null,
  "level_sub": "test2sub",
  "level_top": "test2",
  "group": {
    "groupid": 1,
    "groupname": "Cat1",
    "grouplong": "Testcat1 long",
    "grouplastupdate": "2016-11-30T00:00:00"
   }
 }
  },
  {
    "productid": 183438053218940,
    "date": "2016-12-06T20:45:00",
    "groupid": 2,
    "title": "Testproduct2",
    "description": "Test2",
    "category": null,
    "level_sub": "",
    "level_top": "test2",
    "group": {
      "groupid": 2,
      "groupname": "Cat2",
      "grouplong": "Testcat2 long",
      "grouplastupdate": "2016-11-30T00:00:00"
    }
 "follower":   {
     "productid": 183438053218941,
     "date": "2016-12-06T21:00:00",
     "groupid": 2,
     "title": "Testproduct2bfollow",
     "description": "Test2b",
     "category": null,
     "level_sub": "test3sub",
     "level_top": "test3",
     "group": {
       "groupid": 2,
       "groupname": "Cat2",
       "grouplong": "Testcat2 long",
       "grouplastupdate": "2016-11-30T00:00:00"
  }
  }
}
  
]
```

Is that possible?

Thanks a lot. I am unfortunately still completely overstrained because I am a c# beginner :(

Comment: I have read this 3 times. And each time I found I understood your question less. What are you actually trying to ask?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I try to manipulate the json of my web.api in that form that I get of each group 2 items - the first a root and the second as a child (follower in my example). That would be easy to loop in angular (I will show 1  <div class="col-xs-9...> per group.

Comment: Your question is not clearly written. It sounds like you want to add `follower` information to the web api output. So add it to the `include`. If that is not what you meant you need to add more detail where this json in coming from and how you are interacting with your web api. Leave bootstrap out of it, it has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I edited the text - hope you understand better what I meant.